# Canonical resource for forms-based design in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, frameworks, view

Is there a resource on the web that describes various form scenarios in ASP.NET MVC, and gives example solutions within a sensible, consistent design philosophy?

Examples of such scenarios might be:

1. One-to-many forms, like invoice data-entry forms.
2. Foreign-table forms such as Add New User in a form that requires specifying a user
3. Forms that require dynamic interaction, using Ajax or JSON.
4. Popup forms
5. Forms requiring multiple data records to be input, without postbacks.

Note that there is considerable conceptual and technological overlap among these example scenarios.

I am aware that there is a vast patchwork quilt of available technologies and examples out there that provide partial solutions and pieces of solutions, such as jQuery Ajax, CSS, and so forth.  But I would like guidance in using these technologies in more effective and consistent ways.

I am not considering web forms integration with an ASP.NET MVC application; I would still like my applications to be pure MVC.  Nor am I, at the moment, considering a paid solution like Telerik.

But I would like to know if someone has already done some of the work combining these technologies into a consistent, cohesive whole, that follows a sensible design philosophy. (an open source framework, perhaps?)

Answer (score 1):

[Sharp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) presents a comprehensive framework and best practices for building ASP.NET MVC applications including NHibernate (ORM), Castle Windsor (Dependency Injection) and other useful open-source tools.  They include templates to generate basic CRUD screens.  They are working on an updated version to cover ASP.NET MVC2 with options to use NHibernate or Entity Framework 4 as the ORM.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of Sharp Architecture, will have to dig into it a little deeper.  I'm pretty good with basic CRUD screens; is there anything out there that goes into more advanced form techniques, like the ones I outlined?

Comment: Sharp Architecture is basically t4 generated "dumb" forms with an ocean of plumbing code behind them.  AFAIK it doesn't handle any of the form scenarios @Robert Harvey is talking about.